# Cross-browser javascript function to find actual position of an element in page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

SORRY - MY BAD - There was error in another script that made me think this function is buggy. **
* but hey, you've got a nice function if you need one ;)

Thanks for help guys.

!~~

I got this function:

```
  function findPos(obj) {
      var curleft = curtop = 0;
      if (obj && obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
      }
      return [curleft,curtop];
  }
```

to find and element's actual position in page.

But for some reason, it throws me an error in IE; how do I fix this to work cross-browser?

Comment: It will be much easier for people to help you if you tell us what the error was.

Answer (score 7):

This independent piece of code should get you the offset in modern browsers, without frameworks. It uses the [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) method:

```
function offset(element){
    var body = document.body,
        win = document.defaultView,
        docElem = document.documentElement,
        box = document.createElement('div');
    box.style.paddingLeft = box.style.width = "1px";
    body.appendChild(box);
    var isBoxModel = box.offsetWidth == 2;
    body.removeChild(box);
    box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var clientTop  = docElem.clientTop  || body.clientTop  || 0,
        clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0,
        scrollTop  = win.pageYOffset || isBoxModel && docElem.scrollTop  || body.scrollTop,
        scrollLeft = win.pageXOffset || isBoxModel && docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
    return {
        top : box.top  + scrollTop  - clientTop,
        left: box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) from Jquery.

Comment: hey, i prefer not working with jQuery, as long pure js can perform it.

Comment: This section is for answers.  If you have a question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.