# Getting left and top offset for body element with margin:auto

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent

I'm trying to get the mouse position relative to the body (that is, body = coordinates origin) for a website which has it's body element fixed in size and centered by using the margin:auto CSS attribute.

Since the event.clientX and event.clientY attributes give me the offset from the beginning of the page, not from the body element, I've tried to substract it the body offset. To do so, I've tried to use document.body.offsetLeft & document.body.offsetTop, but no luck so far, the value is undefined. Also, since I didn't define it, I can't use document.body.style.left or document.body.style.top.

Does anybody know a way to get the body offset OR directly get the mouse coordinates relative to a DOM element?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the relative offsets of an element:

```
var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
//bodyOffsets.top   ;
//bodyOffsets.left  ;
```

Comment: Hey thank you! :P
Didn't know that it was possible to get the rendering position directly. Now I feel stupid for calculating the positions relative to the body by looping through the whole hierarchy...

Comment: @gaspercat For a consistent cross-browser solution, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111175/938089).

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery method position() - which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent.

Comment: It seems a good option. I'll keep it in mind, but in that case I'm not using Jquery anywhere else on the project.